# How to parse an empty string into a None?

Tags: rust

What is the idiomatic way to handle the parsing of an empty string into a `None` and not a `Some("")`?

```
let handle: Option<String> = x.get(0).and_then(|v| v.parse().ok());
```

Answer (score 15):

If you start with a `String`:

```
let string = String::new();
let handle = Some(string).filter(|s| !s.is_empty());
```

Since Rust 1.50 you can also use `bool::then` (thanks sebpuetz)

```
let handle = string.is_empty().not().then(|| string);
// or
let handle = (!string.is_empty()).then(|| string);
```

With your code:

```
let handle = x.get(0)
    .and_then(|v| v.parse().ok())
    .filter(String::is_empty);
```

**Docs**

- [String::is_empty](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.is_empty)
- [Option::filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter)
- [bool::then](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then)

Comment: With the recently added `bool::then` you can get around explicitly constructing an `Option<String>`: `let s = String::new(); (!s.is_empty()).then(|| s);` returns `None`.

Since OP is already getting an `Option` out of `x.get()`, your second snippet is preferrable anyways!

Comment: Your first example converts `""` to `Some("")` instead of `None`.

Comment: and now in rust 1.62 there's `then_some(string)`

Comment: Doesn't `.filter(String::is_empty)` do the opposite of what you want?
Wouldn't you want `.filter(|s| !s.is_empty())`?