# How can I ask for an optional input with dialoguer?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get an optional input from [dialoguer](https://docs.rs/dialoguer/latest/dialoguer/):

```rs
let name: Option<String> = Input::with_theme(&ColorfulTheme::default())
    .with_prompt("Name")
    .interact()
    .unwrap();
```

but I was not able to find a feature in dialoguer that supports this. Is there a piece of the API that I'm missing, or will I simply have to check for an empty string?

Comment: I'm using `let name: String=Input::<String>::with_theme(&ColorfulTheme::default())
                .with_prompt("Name")
                .interact_text()?;`
and then check `if name.len() == 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [convert an empty string into a None using bool::then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683721/how-to-parse-an-empty-string-into-a-none)

```rs
let name: Option<String> = Input::with_theme(&ColorfulTheme::default())
    .with_prompt("Ferret's name")
    .interact()
    .map(|s: String| s.is_empty().not().then(|| s))
    .unwrap();
```